# Datepicker default date should be yesterday and always start with month first day

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want datepicker always show yesterday date and in mindate it should show last three month dates but always it should consider months 1st date.

CODE:

```
$scope.searchFromDate = timeStamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
          $scope.searchToDate = timeStamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    $( "#searchFromDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',maxDate:0 , minDate:"-3M"});
    $("#searchFromDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
    $( "#searchToDate" ).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd',maxDate:0 , minDate:"-3M"});
    $("#searchToDate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

And also want to select date only for one day,Suppose I have selected 2018-11-02 from date then to date it should be 2018-11-03 and all other should be disable.So it means user can select only one day which can be any date but only for a one day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set -1 in second parameter means yesterday date

```
$("#searchToDate").datepicker("setDate", -1);
```

Comment: ok Thanks,But how we can make previous month restriction should calculate from current date to last 3month but if date is in middle it should always start from 1st.